# connection refused when connecting to web server

Tags: c, networking

I'm trying to connect to a web server so I can scrape it but my program gives me the error: "Connection refused" coming from the connect function. heres the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <regex.h>

#define MAXLINE 4096

int main() {
    char domain[255];
    char netAddr[255];
    char GETrqst[MAXLINE];
    char recvLine[MAXLINE];
    int rl;

    printf("webscraper\n\n");

    printf("enter the domain of the website you want to scrape (eg: google.com): ");
    scanf("%s", domain);

    //address struct
    //2 structs for the getaddrinfo function
    struct addrinfo getResult, *getResult2;
    memset(&getResult, 0, sizeof(getResult));
    getResult.ai_family = AF_INET;
    getResult.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;


    int addrErr = getaddrinfo(domain, NULL, &getResult, &getResult2);

    if (addrErr != 0) {
        perror("getaddrinfo");
        exit(1);
    }

        //first half of ip
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, getResult2->ai_addr->sa_data, netAddr, 255)) {
        //second half of ip
        void *addr_in = &((struct sockaddr_in *) getResult2->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, addr_in, netAddr, 255);

        printf("ip for domain is: %s\n", netAddr);
    } else {
        perror("inet_ntop");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in socket_address;
    //memset(&socket_address, 0, sizeof(socket_address));
    socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_address.sin_port = htons(80);

    int atonErr = inet_aton(getResult2->ai_addr->sa_data, &socket_address.sin_addr);

    if (atonErr != 0) {
        perror("inet_aton");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("successfully converted string to struct\n");
    }

    freeaddrinfo(getResult2);

    printf("address struct setup\n");

    sleep(1);

    printf("setting up socket\n");

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    sleep(1);

    printf("attempting connection to web server...\n");
    int connectStatus = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));

    if (connectStatus == -1) {
        perror("connect error");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("connection success!\n");
    }

    sleep(1);
    //sets get command to get webpage. \r\n\r\n is at the end of every webpage url
    sprintf(GETrqst, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");

    write(sock, GETrqst, sizeof(GETrqst));

    memset(recvLine, 0, MAXLINE);
    
    while ((rl = read(sock, recvLine, MAXLINE-1)) > 0 ) {
        printf("%s", recvLine);
    }

    exit(1);

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried using memset() to reset the sockaddr_in struct because that worked before but now it isn't working. I also checked if the ip was being saved and used properly and it is but none of those options worked. I'm very lost and i've been trying to fix this for about 2 hours. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A firewall may be blocking you.

Comment: ive tried connecting to other sites and im still not able to connect

Comment: Can you connect to those sites using `telnet` or `netcat`?

Comment: If you use `tcpdump` or `Wireshark`, do you see the connection being attempted to the correct IP?

Comment: ill use netcat and wireshark and see if it gives me anything

Comment: i used netcat and it gives me an error 400

Comment: The 400 is a response from the web server. It _did_ connect. The error is an HTTP error code. I downloaded your program and ran it here for google.com It produces the _same_ error. To summarize, you _can_ connect to the [any] website (i.e. you _will_ get your app's `connection success!` message), but the website does _not_ like your `GET` command.

Comment: Barmar, ive used wireshark and i cant find anything about my program attempting a connection to google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes to get it to make a successful HTTP request:

- Added the `Host:` field to the HTTP 1.1 request. It's an error not to supply that field.
- I made it send the proper amount of bytes for `GETrqst`. It should be `strlen(GETrqst)`, not `sizeof(GETrqst)`.
- You copy the wrong thing into `socket_address.sin_addr` in `inet_aton(getResult2->ai_addr->sa_data, &socket_address.sin_addr);`. You have the correct thing in `((struct sockaddr_in *) getResult2->ai_addr)->sin_addr` and need only to copy that.

With my changes:

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MAXLINE 4096

int main() {
    char domain[255];
    char GETrqst[MAXLINE];
    char recvLine[MAXLINE];

    printf("webscraper\n\n");

    printf("enter the domain of the website you want to scrape (eg: google.com): ");
    if(scanf("%254s", domain) != 1) return 1;

    // address struct
    // 2 structs for the getaddrinfo function
    struct addrinfo getResult = {0}, *getResult2;
    getResult.ai_family = AF_INET;
    getResult.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    getResult.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    int addrErr = getaddrinfo(domain, NULL, &getResult, &getResult2);

    if(addrErr != 0) {
        perror("getaddrinfo");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("attempting connection to web server...\n");

    int sock;
    struct addrinfo *rp;
    // loop through the possible addresses
    for (rp = getResult2; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
        sock = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
        if (sock == -1) {
            perror("socket");
            continue;
        }
        printf("socket created - connecting ...\n");

        /* if you want to show the IP
        char netAddr[255];
        void* addr_in = &((struct sockaddr_in*)rp->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, addr_in, netAddr, sizeof netAddr);
        printf("IP: %s\n", netAddr);
        */

        struct sockaddr_in socket_address;
        socket_address.sin_family = rp->ai_family; // AF_INET;
        socket_address.sin_port = htons(80);
        socket_address.sin_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in*)rp->ai_addr)->sin_addr;

        if (connect(sock, (const struct sockaddr*) &socket_address,
                          sizeof socket_address) != -1) 
        {
            // connection success
            break;
        }
        perror("connect");

        close(sock);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(getResult2);

    if(rp == NULL) {
        printf("failed to connect\n");
        return 1;
    }

    sleep(1);

    printf("connection success!\n");

    sleep(1);

    sprintf(GETrqst, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s:80\r\n\r\n", domain);

    write(sock, GETrqst, strlen(GETrqst));

    ssize_t rl;
    while((rl = read(sock, recvLine, sizeof recvLine - 1)) > 0) {
        recvLine[rl] = '\0';
        fputs(recvLine, stdout);
    }
}
```

Note: Most sites use HTTPS nowadays so, unless you know that the site you are trying to scrape is available through plain HTTP, you may need to add encryption too. If you do an HTTP request to `google.com:80` it'll answer something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 07 Sep 2021 18:57:22 GMT
Expires: Thu, 07 Oct 2021 18:57:22 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: that helps but the problem is that the connection is being refused. not the http request

Comment: @logsInMyEyes69 Are you on a network with firewalls/proxies?

Comment: @logsInMyEyes69 If I run your program and connect to `google.com` it connects fine and, with my changes, makes a successful request. Google answers with a `>301 Moved Permanently` (but the request was successful).

Comment: so i just attempted to connect to a localhost webpage and it works. now i need to make it connect to google.com

Comment: @logsInMyEyes69 Great! That means that the two things I added made your program work - as long as it can actually reach the destination host. You now need to figure out what it is that is blocking your access to the outside.

Comment: @logsInMyEyes69 I noticed that you had more problems in the code. I fixed those I could find and updated the answer.

Comment: tysm for doing all of that. my program works now!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my top comments, your app *did* connect to the website. But, it did *not* like your HTTP request and returned http error 400.

But, that was incorrect. It connected to *a* website but *not* the desired one.

There were two issues.

1. `sin_addr` in your `connect` call was all zeroes (i.e. `0.0.0.0`)
2. Your HTTP request was incomplete.

---

Your code:

```
inet_aton(getResult2->ai_addr->sa_data, &socket_address.sin_addr);
```

was storing all zeroes.

I commented it out and did a `memcpy` from your `inet_ntop` call:

```
if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, getResult2->ai_addr->sa_data, netAddr, 255)) {
    // second half of ip
    void *addr_in = &((struct sockaddr_in *) getResult2->ai_addr)->sin_addr;

    inet_ntop(AF_INET, addr_in, netAddr, 255);

    printf("%sip for domain is: %s\n", T_GREEN, netAddr);

    memcpy(&socket_address.sin_addr,addr_in,
        sizeof(socket_address.sin_addr));
}
```

---

Your request was incomplete. It needs a `Host:` field.

So, you want to send:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: <url_of_server>\r\n
\r\n
```

---

Here's the final code I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <regex.h>
//#include "tColor copy.h"

#define MAXLINE 4096

#define T_RED       "RED: "
#define T_GREEN     "GREEN: "
#define T_BLUE      "BLUE: "

#define SENDLINE(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        buflen = sprintf(buf, _fmt); \
        printf("SENDLINE: %s\n",buf); \
        strcpy(&buf[buflen],"\r\n"); \
        write(sock, buf, buflen + 2); \
    } while (0)

char buf[MAXLINE];
size_t buflen;

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char domain[255];
    char netAddr[255];
    size_t Getlen;
    char GETrqst[MAXLINE];
    char recvLine[MAXLINE];
    int rl;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    printf("%swebscraper\n\n", T_GREEN);

    if (argc > 0) {
        strcpy(domain,argv[0]);
        printf("domain is '%s'\n",domain);
    }
    else {
        printf("%senter the domain of the website you want to scrape (eg: google.com): ", T_BLUE);
        scanf("%s", domain);
    }

    // address struct
    // 2 structs for the getaddrinfo function
    struct addrinfo getResult,
    *getResult2;

    memset(&getResult, 0, sizeof(getResult));
    getResult.ai_family = AF_INET;
    getResult.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    int addrErr = getaddrinfo(domain, NULL, &getResult, &getResult2);

    if (addrErr != 0) {
        printf("%s", T_RED);
        perror("getaddrinfo");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in socket_address;

    // first half of ip
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, getResult2->ai_addr->sa_data, netAddr, 255)) {
        // second half of ip
        void *addr_in = &((struct sockaddr_in *) getResult2->ai_addr)->sin_addr;

        inet_ntop(AF_INET, addr_in, netAddr, 255);

        printf("%sip for domain is: %s\n", T_GREEN, netAddr);

        memcpy(&socket_address.sin_addr,addr_in,
            sizeof(socket_address.sin_addr));
    }
    else {
        printf("%s", T_RED);
        perror("inet_ntop");
        exit(1);
    }

    // memset(&socket_address, 0, sizeof(socket_address));
    socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_address.sin_port = htons(80);

#if 0
    int atonErr = inet_aton(getResult2->ai_addr->sa_data, &socket_address.sin_addr);

    if (atonErr != 0) {
        printf("%s", T_RED);
        perror("inet_aton");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("%ssuccessfully converted string to struct\n", T_GREEN);
    }
#endif

    freeaddrinfo(getResult2);

    printf("%saddress struct setup\n", T_GREEN);

    sleep(1);

    printf("%ssetting up socket\n", T_BLUE);

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    sleep(1);

    printf("%sattempting connection to web server...\n", T_BLUE);
    int connectStatus = connect(sock,
        (struct sockaddr *) &socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));

    if (connectStatus == -1) {
        printf("%s", T_RED);
        perror("connect error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("%sconnection success!\n", T_GREEN);
    }

    //sleep(1);
    // sets get command to get webpage. \r\n\r\n is at the end of every webpage url
    SENDLINE("GET / HTTP/1.1");
    //SENDLINE("Host: %s",netAddr);
    SENDLINE("Host: %s",domain);
    SENDLINE("Accept: */*");
    //SENDLINE("Connection: keep-alive");
    SENDLINE("");

    memset(recvLine, 0, MAXLINE);

    while ((rl = read(sock, recvLine, MAXLINE - 1)) > 0) {
        //printf("%s", recvLine);
        fwrite(recvLine,1,rl,stdout);
    }

    exit(1);

    return 0;
}
```